# Setting properties file using java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a Swing Frame with some text-fields which displays the current values in the Properties file. Once I modify these properties in the text-field it should be saved back to the properties file. The properties which I have are database connection parameters. My connection parameters are as follows

```
driver--org.postgresql.Driver
url--jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bank
user--postgres
password--aaa
```

But when it updates, in the url field, where ever there is a ':', it adds a '\'
like `URL2=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost/bank`. How can I avoid this? I tried printing the contents before setting the Properties file and then it is ok. 
I printed the String before setting the properties, there it is coming right;

```
org.postgresql.Driver  **jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bank**postgres**aaa
```

Can someone please help me.
Thanks in Advance

```
 public static void update(String driver,String url, String user,String password) throws SecurityException, IOException{
        System.out.println(driver+"  **"+url+"**"+user+"**"+password);

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("evaluator.properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(in);
        in.close();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("evaluator.properties");
        props.setProperty("Driver2", driver);
        props.setProperty("URL2", url);
        props.setProperty("Login2", user);
        props.setProperty("Password2", password);
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, it will work all the same; but yeah, it is annoying

Comment: This is how the properties API works, it needs escape certain characters.  When you read the properties back in (via the `Properties` class) how do they look?

Comment: As @MadProgrammer mentioned, if you add a `props.list(System.err);` directly after your `props.load(in);` line, you can verify that after reloading the properties look fine

Comment: @MadProgrammer:thanks. When i read the URL back, it displays in the way I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Properties.store()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) escapes certain characters:

> The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.

Once you read them back with [`Properties.load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29), they are unescaped so that you will get the original value.

Comment: your typing speed is fast than me ... :-p

Comment: @Shinchan It primarily depends on how fast you find the docs ;-)

Comment: @Andrew:Thanks a lot for the explanantion

Answer (score 1):

As per [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) for 
store API , some characters will be escaped while writing to an outputstream.

So, the colon ":" is getting converted to "\:"

I hope the solution would be to escape the characters before writing to outputstream.
While converting back to properties instance, the escape characters will be treated as required.

Comment: Thanks for the explanantion